# Python: how to tell if input file has input pending without waiting

Tags: python, python-2.7

Normally, you process a file line by line in Python using a loop like:

```
import sys
for s in sys.stdin:
    # do something with the line in s
```

or

```
import sys
while True:
    line = sys,stdin.readline()
    if len(line) == 0: break
    # process input line
```

Of course, you can also use raw_input() in soemthing like this:

```
try:
    while True:
        s = raw_input()
        # process input line
except EOFError:
    # there's EOF.
```

Of course in all these cases, if there's no input ready to be read, the underlying `read()` operation suspends waiting for I/O.

What I want to do is see if there is input pending **without** suspending, so I can read until input is exhausted and then go do something else.  That is, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
while "there is input pending":
    #get the input
```

but when no more input is pending, break the loop.

Comment: What platform is the code supposed to run on?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936594/how-can-you-tell-if-a-python-program-has-anything-to-read-from-stdin

Comment: I'd rather find something that's platform independent, that's why I didn't specify.

Comment: Hm.  The question is similar to the linked question, which then links *another* question, which leads to a fairly atrocious 20-odd lines of code using `Queue.nowait()` and a separate thread.  Is there really no simpler way to just look?

Comment: @CharlieMartin: If you want to support basically all operating systems except for Windows, there are several ways.  If you also want to support Windows, you have to use threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, [here's something](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/) that works well on UNIX:

```
import sys
import select
import tty
import termios


def isData():
    return select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], [])

old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
try:
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())

    i = 0
    while 1:
        print i
        i += 1

        if isData():
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            if c == '\x1b':         # x1b is ESC
                break

finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

I'll modify/extend this answer when I have a chance to make a somewhat better test program.  I'm (so far) unclear on how well `tty` and `termios` work on Windows.

**Update**: Grmph.  This depends on `select`.  There are reasons I don't like Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some variant of Unix, and your standard input is a pipe and not a file, you can use the [`select` module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) to check to see whether there is waiting input. At a minimum, the code might look like:

```
import select

rlist, wlist, elist = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
if rlist:
    s = raw_input()
else:
    pass # no input ready right now
```

Comment: well, I'd like to be independent of the platform, and the input might well be a file or /dev/tty.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: On Unix, you can actually `select()` on any file descriptor., but the semantics for files will be slightly different than for pipes.  Anyway, this is not platform-indepedent.