# Python getpass.getpass() function call hangs

Tags: python-2.7, freeze, getpasswd

I am trying to get a prompt that will ask for my password but when I try to call `getpass.getpass()` it just freezes. I am running on Windows 7 64 bit using Python 2.7 on Canopy.

```
import sys
import getpass

p = getpass.getpass()
print p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python "effectively freezes because it can't receive the input from standard input". See https://support.enthought.com/entries/22157050-Canopy-Python-prompt-QtConsole-Can-t-run-getpass-or-interactive-OS-shell-commands-or-Windows-process

The fix is to use a different interpreter. I switched to IDLE and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

It is correct that Python "effectively freezes because it can't receive the input from standard input", however, for windows you can prefix your command with `winpty`. Then password can be inputted correctly when started like:

```
winpty python fileToExecute.py
```

[winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) provides a interface similar to a Unix pty-master in a way that communication is also possible from windows terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue with getpass (mingw64) and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616813/can-i-get-console-input-without-echo-in-python) simple solution.

```
os.system("stty -echo")
password = input('Enter Password:')
os.system("stty echo")
print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

`getpass()` will freeze if python is unable to read properly from standard input.
This can happen on e.g. some Windows terminals, such as using git bash.
You can use the `sys` module to [detect if this will happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/699390/28037), to avoid hanging:

```
import getpass
import sys

# ...

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    # notify user that they have a bad terminal
    # perhaps if os.name == 'nt': , prompt them to use winpty?
    return
else:
    password = getpass.getpass()
    # ...
```

Comment: I just tested this - it does not work in all cases. Ex: On PyCharm in Windows hitting run would cause the terminal to hang however if I debugged it worked. Using this fix it rejects both instances.

Comment: It did work for all the other use cases in which I tried it. So I'm still using it though!

Comment: @GrantCurell Thanks for the feedback. Do you have a suggestion for a fix or alternate code that would work with PyCharm? Any idea why PyCharm hangs?

Comment: I honestly don't - I'm not actually sure why it's doing it. I played with it for a bit, but honestly it only happened in PyCharm. I'm not sure what the difference is with its debug terminal, but on the regular Windows command line I had no problems which is what the people using my code are going to see anyway so I left it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this on mac with both Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook. For me the issue was caused by the variable name.

Naming the variable `PG_REMOTEPASSWORD` caused a hang but `PG_PASSWORD` & `PG_ABCPass` didn't. I don't know why that is an issue, there's nothing in docs about restrictions on what a variable can be called.

My setup up is Anaconda running Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm RUN i had similar issue. When i opened files using Terminal "CMD" issue resolved.