# Python getpass doesn't work on Windows Git Bash (MINGW64)

Tags: python, windows

I have this simple python code to get a password without echoing it.

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
print(password)
```

This code works as expected on Linux, but on Windows Git Bash it let's me type indefinitely. As a workaround I can use the script from PowerShell, but it's annoying to change shells just to run a script.

Do you know any other non-echoing libraries in Python or any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544353/python-getpass-getpass-function-call-hangs

Comment: @Felics edited my answer which didn't work for a completely different solution which seems to work on MSYS at least.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The issue is the same: "it can't receive the input from standard input"

Comment: yes, but the solution isn't: "As a workaround I can use the script from PowerShell". OP knows it is a terminal issue but OP would like to avoid switching terminals

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash: `alias python='winpty python.exe'`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Right, I didn't say it was the solution.  I said it was the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general issue seems to be similar to this: [Python getpass.getpass() function call hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544353/python-getpass-getpass-function-call-hangs)  i.e. python isn't able to read from stdio.  An answer here: [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash) has a solution that worked for me:

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'
```

This fixes issues with reading from stdio in general allowing getpass to work as expected.

This approach leads to another error when attempting to redirect to file: `stdout is not a tty`  Changing the alias to this resolved that issue:

```
alias python='winpty -Xallow-non-tty python.exe'
```

As explained in an answer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1011597/what-does-an-output-is-not-a-tty-error-mean

Comment: nice mix of both answers

Answer (score 3):

That works with my MSYS/Git bash terminal, where `getpass` or solutions using `mscvrt` don't and print characters (and don't capture them)

```
import subprocess,sys

sys.stdout.write("Password: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
subprocess.check_call(["stty","-echo"])
password = input()
subprocess.check_call(["stty","echo"])
print("\npassword: {}".format(password))
```

the trick is to call `stty` to suppress output, get the password using a standard `input()` call, then turn on output with `stty` again